# NumberFormatException in solr

Tags: solr

I have a file containing multiple informations (in french) :

```
id,nom_voie,id_fantoir,numero,rep,code_insee,code_post,alias,nom_ld,nom_afnor,libelle_acheminement,x,y,lon,lat,nom_commune
ADRNIVX_0000000285796714,,B029,5269,"",01294,01300,"",FAY,,PEYRIEU,907611.7,6510483,5.66671358522653,45.6623440803523,Peyrieu
ADRNIVX_0000000285615528,,B072,5203,"",01104,01200,"",LE CREUX,,CHEZERY FORENS,919429.7,6567424,5.84472395497885,46.1710686783583,Chézery-Forens
ADRNIVX_0000000285665373,,A020,6,"",01335,01240,"","",,ST ANDRE LE BOUCHOUX,860345.8,6559577.8,5.07649444520238,46.1170232380819,Saint-André-le-Bouchoux
```

The two first lines are parsed correctly, but the third one give an error :

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">400</int>
        <int name="QTime">53</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="error">
        <lst name="metadata">
            <str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
            <str name="root-error-class">java.lang.NumberFormatException</str>
        </lst>
        <str name="msg">ERROR: [doc=ADRNIVX_0000000285665373] Error adding field 'y'='6559577.8' msg=For input string:     "6559577.8"</str>
        <int name="code">400</int>
    </lst>
</response>
```

Solr can't parse my y value "6559577.8". But in the previous lines the x value is of the same format. If I remove the ".8" the line is parsed. What is wrong with the y value ? Should I specify a format somewhere ?

Comment: is there any chance that you may miss any value, that could be the cause of the number format exception....As I see the third has one missing value..

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti No I don't think so, all values are here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the first line had an integer for the y value, so solr mapped it in an integer. I created another collection with a float value for the first line and it was ok

Answer (score 3):

what is the field def for that value??

the previous two lines had no point value in there, so if you are using schemaless mode, Solr would have mapped that field to an int/long, then it fails the first time it finds a float.